# PHP script stops // looping through table

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, timeout

I have a very simple script looping through a MySQL-Table (3500 records) and returning the result in an HTML-Table.

The scripts ends suddenly (after 500) without error and without reaching the end of the table.

Any ideas whats wrong? Many thanks for comments.

Cheers
Tim

```
echo "<h1>This is PHP version " . phpversion() . "</h1>"; // returns 7.1.10
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

echo "<h3>Script Runtime: ". ini_get('max_execution_time') ." Sec.</h3>"; // returns 300
echo "<h3>Memory Limit: ". ini_get('memory_limit') ."</h3>"; // retuns 100M

$i = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblClients ORDER BY lastname, firstname";
if (! $recClients = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $sql)) {die("<p><b>SQL:</b><br>".$sql."</p>");}

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo   "<th>Nr.</th>";
    echo   "<th>Firstname</th>";
    echo   "<th>Lastname</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($rowClients = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recClients)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo   "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
        echo   "<td>" . $rowClients['firstname'] . "</td>";
        echo   "<td>" . $rowClients['lastname']  . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: what is the variable `$recClients` that is being used in `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: thanks for the hint. This was just a "addapting to public" error. I corrected my post.

Comment: Why don't you think it runs through them all? It does for me, when I fixed the syntax error at `if (! $recClients = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {die("<p><b>SQL:</b><br>".$sql."</p>"));}`

Comment: thanks again. The syntax error was again a mistake by writing the post here, but for sure is not in my "real" script. --> It does not run through them all because it returns only / stops after 500 of 3500 records.

Comment: Does it exceed 30 seconds to retrieve the 500 records? Try and increase the max execution time, and memory limit in your `php.ini`

Comment: I tried already `ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);` but no changes in the output... as far as I know changing the `php.ini` or setting this command should be the same, or? And memory of 100M should be ok as well, or?

Comment: It should, be just to test it. Because in theory there is nothing wrong with the code. So it's either a bad connection, or something timing out.

Comment: i tested changes on `max_execution_time`and `memory_limit` in `php.ini` --> no change in the returned output